# How can I remove nested loop multiplication repetition?

Tags: python, nested-loops

I'm using a nested loop to run through all the products of 3 digit numbers but I want to avoid repetitions (`200 * 800` and then later `800 * 200`).

I have no idea where to even start on this. I was thinking of breaking the first loop when `x * y` is above a certain point but then it would never reach `1000 * 1000`.

```
for x in range(100, 1000):
    for y in range(100, 1000):
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just make `y` start at `x` instead of all the way back from `100`:

```
for x in range(100, 1000):
    for y in range(x, 1000):
```

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid repetition by having the second for loop range from x to 1000. Below is the code for the same.

```
for x in range(100, 1000):
    for y in range(x, 1000):
```